# Update in a join with sub-query

Tags: mysql, sql

```
UPDATE item t 

INNER JOIN ( SELECT
               item_name,
               MAX( item_keyword ) AS item_keyword
             FROM item
             WHERE ca_id2  = '2010'
             GROUP BY item_name
           ) s ON t.item_name = s.item_name

SET t.item_keyword = s.item_keyword 

WHERE t.ca_id2 ='3010'
```

The error is:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax.  Check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL    server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'SELECT item_name, max(item_keyword) AS item_keyword
>        FROM item

MySQL version 4.0.22 What is the reason for the failure?

Comment: Yowza.... `4.0.22`. I'm all for supporting somewhat older versions, but this is _ancient_. However: [_"Currently, you cannot update a table and select from the same table in a subquery."_](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/update.html).

Comment: See http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/06/23/how-to-select-from-an-update-target-in-mysql/

Comment: I am a beginner..Too difficult. T.T

Answer (score 1):

I tried to construct your query based on 
http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/06/23/how-to-select-from-an-update-target-in-mysql/

```
UPDATE item t

SET t.item_keyword =
      ( SELECT MAX( i.item_keyword ) AS item_keyword
          FROM ( SELECT item_keyword, item_name, cd_id2 FROM item ) AS i
         WHERE t.item_name = i.item_name
           AND i.cd_id2  = '2010'
      GROUP BY i.item_name
      )

WHERE t.ca_id2 ='3010'
```

Or you can try this version too

```
UPDATE item t

INNER JOIN ( SELECT item_keyword, item_name, cd_id2 FROM item ) AS i

SET t.item_keyword =
      ( SELECT MAX( i.item_keyword ) AS item_keyword
          FROM i
         WHERE t.item_name = i.item_name
           AND i.cd_id2  = '2010'
      GROUP BY i.item_name
      )

WHERE t.ca_id2 ='3010'
```

Sorry, I don't have MySQL 4 around, so you have to test the above queries.

Other readings:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/update.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/rewriting-subqueries.html

If the above queries don't work, you can try using a temporary table instead of the subselect:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/13ccb/1

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE s
   SELECT item_name,
          MAX( item_keyword ) AS item_keyword
    FROM  item
    WHERE cd_id2  = '2010'
      AND item.item_name IN ( SELECT item_name FROM item WHERE item.ca_id2='3010')
GROUP BY item_name;


UPDATE item t 
INNER JOIN s ON t.item_name = s.item_name
SET t.item_keyword = s.item_keyword 
WHERE t.ca_id2 ='3010';

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE s;
```

Comment: Is it still throwing syntax error? My first query works in MySQL 5.5: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/81f50/2

Comment: syntax error... mysql 4.0.22... Can not change mysql version. The reason is because hosting service. I want the query available in 4.0.22

Comment: If you know the answer please let me know.I need the 4.0.22 queries.

Comment: Is the temporary table method not working? It should be simple enough for MySQL 4.

Comment: I'M PHPMYADMIN USE. CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE s 
   SELECT item_name, 
          MAX( item_keyword ) AS item_keyword 
    FROM  item 
    WHERE cd_id2  = '2010' 
      AND item.item_name IN ( SELECT item_name FROM item WHERE item.ca_id2='3010') 
GROUP BY item_name; 
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax.  Check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT item_name FROM item WHERE item.ca_id2='3010') 
GROUP BY 
T.T After copying the item table and join not work?

Comment: I don't know what is the problem. Maybe try removing `AND item.item_name IN ( SELECT item_name FROM item WHERE item.ca_id2='3010')`, even if it makes the temp table bigger.

Comment: AND item.item_name IN ( SELECT item_name FROM item WHERE item.ca_id2='3010' REMOVING. Was performed correctly.